# Control size of report Using Report Viewer for SSRS in WSS

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, reportbuilder

Is there a way using ReportBuilder to set the size of a report such that there will be no scrollbars displayed in the Report Viewer Web Part for a smallish report?

Comment: It appears that regardless of the size of the actual content the report viewer allocates an entire page width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the page size of the report in report builder fixed the issue.  There is a strange refresh issue with Internet explorer but that is another question.